# There was an error activating the remote language server, c#/Visual Basic Language Server client

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I open any project in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.4, even a simple newly created .net core console project. I get the error message:

> There was an error activating the remote language server, c#/Visual Basic Language Server client.

Afterwards there is no IntelliSense and even though I am able to run a build of the project no errors or warnings appear in visual studio.

The activity monitor log shows the following errors:

- Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CppSvc.Internal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.VCPlugin.dll
- Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.Client, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\platform\diagnosticshub\Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Package.dll
- Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.RecommendationProvider, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\INTELLICODE\IntelliCodeCpp.dll

I have tried to restart visual studio, restart windows, repair visual studio, uninstall visual studio and install it again. I have run the netFxRepairTool. Still running into the issue.

The files, that are mentioned in the log are all present at the expected location.

Comment: I was having this error yesterday after apply the update version 16.9.2.
Every time I open a Git repository, do a stash or a pop a commit, I always getting this error.
After I set on the menu "Git->Local Repositories->Folder..." the correct folder, I stopped receiving this error. The reason is that repo was inside a sub-folder of the default local.
I think this is a bug because the VS2019 should use the root of the application folder.
But also this error may be due to another reason. I just exposed my case. Edit:
Sorry, after restarting VS the error still appear again. My bad. But the origin o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix was provided by Microsoft for this issue. See https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/There-was-an-error-activating-the-remote/1313889?entry=problem for details. You can download the fix at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: I am still having it in version 16.10.3 for Angular Language Service Extension

Comment: Yes, sometimes it's still there. in my case however nothing to do with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the errors that are shown in the activity log by doing the following:

1. I have deinstalled .NET Core SDK 1.0.0 (x64) Installer (x64)
2. Repaired Visual Studio
3. Restarted Windows
4. Installed .NET desktop environment (via visual studio installer)

Now all errors in the activity log are gone, but Visual studio is still not working. It is still showing the same error as before:

> There was an error activating the remote language server, c#/Visual Basic Language Server client.

Now I have the following warnings in my activity log (these havn't been there before):

- Request for "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Internal.SettingsManager (1.0)" from Process denied because the service is only exposed RemoteExclusiveClient, LiveShareGuest.
- Request for proxy to "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Internal.SettingsManager (1.0)" is declined: ServiceAudienceMismatch.

Then I removed Visual Studio 2019 and installed Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview 3.0. Now everything is up and running again. Please be aware that it wasn't enough to install the preview in parallel to the old version. The old version had to be removed first, before the error disappeared.

Comment: I have the exact same two errors as above. I can't even start the visual studio installer for repair or uninstall.

Comment: I have the same issue. I already uninstall my VS and reinstall it but nothing works.